# Selenium WebDriver based framework using POM with java

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to write code to validate a webpage (Test Form with 3 required fields firstname, lastname, phone and 2 buttons submit and clear form) using POM with Selenium WebDriver with Java.

This is the code which I have written so far. I want to confirm whether I am going in the right way.

```
public class TestForm {
  WebDriver driver;

  By firstName=By.id("fname");
  By lastName=By.id("lname");
  By phoneno=By.id("phone");
  By submit=By.id("submit");
  By clearForm=By.xpath("//tagname[@type='button']");

  public TestForm(WebDriver driver)
  {
    this.driver=driver;
  }

  public void typeFirstName(String fname)
  {
    driver.findElement(firstName).sendKeys(fname);
  }

  public void typeLastName(String lname)
  {
    driver.findElement(lastName).sendKeys(lname);
  }

  public void typePhone(String phone)
  {
    driver.findElement(phoneno).sendKeys(phone);
  }

  public void clickSubmit()
  {
    driver.findElement(submit).click();
  }

  public void clickClearForm()
  {
    driver.findElement(clearForm).click();
  } 

}
```

---

```
public class VerifyTestForm {

  @Test
  public void verifyValidTestForm()
  {
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("url of the application");

    TestForm form=new TestForm(driver);
    form.typeFirstName("John");
    form.typeLastName("Adams");
    form.typePhone("1234567890");
    form.clickSubmit();
    form.clickClearForm();
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most code look good, except following items:

1) By clearForm=By.xpath("//tagname[@type='button']"); 
   `tagname` should be a correct tag, like `button` or 'input'

2) After click Submit, the page still stay the form page, If so call `clickClearForm` should work.

```
 form.clickSubmit();
 form.clickClearForm();
```

3) There is no any check point/validation in your code, all are operateion on page.
   // Assume an new page will open after click `Submit` button
   // You need to check the new page opened by check page title if it'll change
   // or check an element belongs to the new page is displayed

```
Assert(driver.getTitle()).toEqual('xxx')
Assert(driver.findElement(xxx).isDisplay()).toBe(true)

// above code may not exact correct, dependent on you choose Junit, TestNG
// or third-party Assert library.    

// After click `Clear/Reset` button, you should check all fields reset to default value
Assert(form.readFirstName()).toEqual("")
```

4) For test class name `VerifyTestForm`, it's better start or end with `Test`, like `Testxxx` or `xxxTest`

Comment: I'm new to selenium. I learning it. Could you please post a sample code with checkpoints. I understood that the checkpoints are set for the mandatory fields. But I have no idea where to insert that code

Answer (score 0):

As your code is correct but it is not the way to implementing Page object Model.

1. You have to use concept of DataProvider to implement framework.
2. Make a excel sheet and extract the data by using DataProvider.
3. Make a new class file from where you can read your excel data.
4. Make a function which return 2d data of the file.
5. So By using this, The way to implement the framework.

Page object Model generally says that we should have to make the separate page of each module which we are using and return the reference of the last page.